# Javascript read once then partially ignored?

Tags: javascript

The following JS is in a script tag beneath my HTML. When the page loads initially, the file seems to work. A channel is created, and when I click on it the console.log statements appear indicating it's operational. I then add a channel successfully. However, when I click on the additional channel, nothing happens. I never reach the `.forEach` and `click` eventListener at the bottom of the page -- a case specifically built for multiple channel buttons. I've tried various configurations and researched the query selectors and forEach. Where am I going wrong?

```
(function() {


    //connect to websocket: copy must be inside request.onload for chat room to register user entry
    let socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);

    if (socket) 
        console.log("Socket connected!");

    socket.on('connect', () => {
        // track number of channels and channel names
        let channelCount = 1;
        let channelList = ["Lobby"];

        // create & display new channels added by user
        let createChannelBtn = document.querySelector('#chanlBtn');

        createChannelBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

            //e.preventDefault();

            let newChannel = document.querySelector('#chanl').value;

            // add a channel if not a duplicate
            if (channelList.indexOf(newChannel) > -1) {

                document.querySelector('#chanl').value = '';

            } else {
                channelCount += 1;
                channelList.push(newChannel);

                console.log(channelList);
                console.log(channelCount);
                let textnode = document.createTextNode(newChannel);
                let node = document.createElement('button');
                node.className += 'dropdown-item';
                node.setAttribute('type', 'button');
                node.setAttribute('id', 'selectChannel');
                node.setAttribute('data-channel-', 'newChannel');
                node.appendChild(textnode);
                document.querySelector('#chanlMenu').appendChild(node);
                document.querySelector('#chanl').value = '';

            }

        });

        if (channelCount == 1) {
            var channel_button = document.querySelector('#selectChannel');
            console.log("channel 1 =" + channel_buttons);
            console.log("channelCount 1 =" + channelCount);
            channel_button.addEventListener('click', function() {
                let room = channel_button.dataset.channel;
                console.log("Inside lobby");
                socket.emit('join', {'username':localStorage.getItem('login'), 'room':room});
            });
        } 

        var channel_buttons = document.querySelectorAll('#selectChannel');


    HERE'S THE SECTION I NEVER REACH AFTER A CHANNEL BUTTON IS ADDED
            channel_buttons.forEach( channel_button => {
                channel_button.addEventListener('click', function() {
                let room = channel_button.dataset.channel;
                console.log("Sending 1 Button signal from Node List");
                //socket.emit('join', {'username':localStorage.getItem('login'), 'room':room});
            });

        });

    });

})()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you add the click handlers to the channel buttons when the page loads.

The problem with this is that the buttons don't exist yet, so you are looping through an empty list created by `var channel_buttons = document.querySelectorAll('#selectChannel');`

(try putting a `console.log(channel_buttons);` after that line to see what the list contains)

You need to either add the event listener to the nodes AFTER they have been created (maybe something like `node.addEventListener(...)` after your `node.appendChild(textnode);` line, or use [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) to put a click handler on the parent that will handle clicks for all of the new buttons.

Comment: I should clarify that on page load a button does exist, so channelCount == 1, I can click on it, and we end up in that block. When I go to create a channel, that gets created, the channelCount goes up, but when I click on it nothing happens.

Comment: The console.log statement said "[object NodeList]".

Comment: I think that is because you create the new button, but you don't add a click handler to it. you added a click handler to the initial existing button, but no code runs to add a click handler to the new buttons when they are created. your forEach only runs once when the script is initially executed, when there is only one button that exists.

Comment: Ok, so your response still stands? If so, I'll look into it. Seems to make sense now. JS and I are not yet friends.

Comment: Yes, I was wrong about the list being empty, it does contain the one button. but the rest of the response stands, I believe.

Comment: Event delegation was a brilliant solution and something I had never heard of before. Infinitely superior to alternative approaches. Thanks!